# are there paid graduate school coaches/consultants (Europe)

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, masters, early-career, biology

I'm a master's student.  I need to hire a coach/consultant who can advise on academic politics and procedures and knows European or Australian/New Zealand unis and available finances.

My google skills are failing me.  Is there a set of search terms to use?  Is there an official name for such a professional for hire?  Or a directory to look in?

To clarify:

- I am *not* looking for a tutor to help me with my coursework.
- I am *not* looking for a ghost writer.
- I am *not* looking for career advice or to switch out of academia.
- I am *not* looking to change projects.  I know what I want to work on.
- I do *not* have a guidance or career counseling option at my uni or program.
- I'm am at Master's level in Biology.

I want to pay someone to give me information on how to navigate grad school options and politics.  I'm trying to google to find such private consultants (term?), but my search results are returning job openings instead of links to paid private consultants -- unhelpful.  I need to know what search terms to use (I know, basic).  Is there a specific, googleable name for such an advisor?  Or a link to some accreditation database or list or company, something.  Have you used such a service?  Does it even exist?  I'm in Europe, so looking for non-US services.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for answers to these questions on this forum.  I want to know if there are professional people who get paid to answer such questions.

Comment: A tutor.  But only a good one.

Comment: Aren't tutors more for learning class material than for finding PIs and schools and grants?  When I google the terms that's the results I see.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. I think the answer is "no." But that's not a reason for closure

Comment: Thanks, Azor, I think your comment might have gotten it to be reopened :).

Comment: ***https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/181499/are-there-paid-graduate-school-coaches-consultants-europe***

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such consultants exist. Try searching for something like "Study in Europe". If you don't find anything relevant then try "Study in Europe consultant".

Off the top of my head, if you're looking at Australia and New Zealand, there is [IDP Education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDP_Education). I know people who used the service, but never used it myself.

Comment: Hey @Allure, thank you for your answer, and sorry it took a while to respond.  The suggestions you made looked good, and I went through and researched them.  Unfortunately, what I found was mostly businesses that specialize in bringing students into Australia and Europe from non-Western countries.  They provide help with visas and applications paperwork, and some advice on university placement, but they don't provide academic advice/coaching.  Thanks again for your work, it just didn't lead to what I needed.

Comment: @gothamgreen academic advice / coaching? As in "if I want to study computational biology where should I go" kind of advice? I doubt there'd be consultants for that kind of advice because you need to be an expert in biology, and most students ask their undergraduate/masters advisors.

Comment: no, like: "I'm writing an email to X to invite them to work with me on project Y.  How do I phrase the first approach and the follow-up?".  Or: "What should I do if I can't find a PI?".  Or: "Give me a list of relevant grants and conferences, and help me understand expected applications formats.".  There are people who advise on this at unis.  Just not my uni.  No advising until I find an advisor, which takes well-crafted emails.  A tautology!  I'm looking to hire someone to answer such questions, and most of the questions aren't super-technical.

Comment: @gothamgreen are you sure consultants like IDP Education aren't able to answer those questions? I would be very surprised if they can't, it seems very much in their job description. Here's another consultancy with a description of what their advisors can do: https://www.useic.org/for-schools "your students can ask basic questions about choosing a college or university, the options available to them, and the application process"